# SQL Data Duplication Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, duplicates, self-join

Greetings of the day!!!!

I have a table having multiple columns of data with different status.

Assume I have 500 rows of data with Status 'Valid' And I have 150 rows of data with `'chkDuplicate'`.

Now I have to write query to Update these 150 records status to Valid or Invalid by comparing few columns for duplication like Address,City,State.

How to achieve this, It needs to support large data tables as well.

Thanks in advance....

TABLE DEFINITION

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ
(
  ID bigint,
  ADDRESS navrchar,
  CITY navrchar,
  STATE nvarchar,
  ZIP nvarchar,
  STATUS
)
```

Status should update based on duplication query.

**Important!!!!** For Duplicate data first record should be valid others should be invalid. If re-process the Invalid data again it should not disturb the valid records.

[image]

If I run query the above table should be same. Record 1,3 should be Success and 3,4 should be 'Duplicate'. Even if i have add few more 1,3 always be in Success other duplicates should be updated to 'Duplicate'.

Comment: please tag the DBMS you are using and also show some sample data and expected result

Comment: Add table definitions, sample table data (as well formatted text), and the expected result. Also tag the dbms you're using, and show us your current query attempt.

Comment: tag DBMS and post your query which you tried

Comment: post some sample data as well as requested in comments

Comment: Important!!!!  For Duplicate data first record should be valid others should be invalid. If re-process the Invalid data it should not disturb the valid records.

Answer (score 0):

This query returned duplicate rows.

```
  select tbl.data1, tbl.data2, tbl.data3
from TestTable1 tbl
inner join (
    SELECT data1 , data2, data3 , COUNT(*) AS dupCount
    FROM TestTable1
    GROUP BY data1, data2, data3
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) oc on tbl.data1 = oc.data1 and tbl.data2 = oc.data2 and tbl.data3 = oc.data3
```

then use Cursor and update duplicate row

[Cursor Expamle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply, Still not able to get the requirement.Plz check updated question.

Comment: You can fill in your own information table... This is solutions and you canchange column , table name or anyone

Comment: I cant use cursors as everything is dynamic like table name and duplicate columns.

Comment: @JaydipJ answer trusted way for your solutions

Answer (score 0):

Added ID for ORDER BY clause then it works for me even if I re-process the duplication call multiple times.

WITH TABLE_DATA_DUPLICATE AS

(SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(

```
  PARTITION BY STREET1,CITY,STATE,ZIP

  ORDER BY STREET1,CITY,STATE,ZIP,ID
```

) NO_OF_REPEATS

FROM YOURTABLE(NOLOCK))

UPDATE TABLE_DATA_DUPLICATE SET STATUS = (CASE WHEN NO_OF_REPEATS = 1 THEN 'VALID' ELSE 'DUPLICATE' END)

Thanks everyone for support.... Cheers!!!!